# PHP Connect to MSSQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I'm trying to connect Microsoft SQL Server

with (PHP 5.6.36):

```
$dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
```

And i get exception :

> "could not find driver"

Picture of `phpinfo()`:

[image]

I searched all over for solutions,but I Couldn't find any post that helped me

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, no SQL-Server Driver is installed

Comment: Type `php -m` on shell console and look for mssql, if it is not there install it first.

Comment: @endo64 mssql not there, i'll install it and try again

Comment: @Double_O_Seven Don't forget to restart the web server after install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help,

I used odbc_connect

```
odbc_connect(
            "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=".$this->hostname.",".$this->port.";Database=".$this->database_name.";MARS_Connection=yes",
            $this->username, $this->password);
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to install PDO drivers for SQL Server:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php